# Wrapping an HTML element - how to implement interface Node

Tags: javascript, inheritance, wrapper

I am creating custom HTML elements and have read that you shouldn't extend the HTMLElement class but create a wrapper for it. I want to be able to use the same syntax for manipulating attributes, properties, and methods as for standard elements: dot notation: `myDiv.id = "id"`, and bracket notation: `myDiv["id"] = "id"`. I would also like to have compatibility with methods. All using vanilla js.

Below is a concept attempt at wrapping a `div` as well as I have been able to figure out.

- Styles - looks like I can assign div.style to my class element and have all properties naturally gettable / settable
- Attributes - I created getters / setters for an attribute list and this works to set attributes e.g. `id`, `innerHTML`, etc.
- events with the `on` syntax - this seems to work with getters and setters.
- methods which "implement interface Element" (e.g. `setAttribute`) - these seem to require defining each one manually
- those operations which use the element that need it to "implement interface Node." e.g. `document.body.appendChild(myDiv)`

My questions in order of importance:

1. Am I going about wrapping elements the "right way?"
2. Is there an acceptable solution for having my element implement interface Node and therefore being able to be used in operations like `document.body.appendChild(myDiv)`?
3. Is there a solution for those methods that "implement interface Element" other than what I did - by defining them one at a time?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var myDiv = new DivWrapper();
  document.body.appendChild(myDiv.div);

  // using the style property object
  myDiv.style.height = "200px";
  myDiv.style.width = "200px";
  myDiv.style.background = "aliceblue";

  // using manually created methods setAttribute() getAttribute()
  myDiv.setAttribute("id", "newId");
  
  // using automatically generated getter and setter
  myDiv.innerHTML = "Height: " + myDiv.style.height;
  myDiv.innerHTML += "<br>id: " + myDiv.getAttribute("id");
  myDiv.contentEditable = "true";

  // listener - using getter setter
  myDiv.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log("Click")
  };
}

DivWrapper = (function() {
  var instanceCounter = 0;

  function DivWrapper() {
    this.id = "div" + instanceCounter++;
    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.style = this.div.style;

    var attributes = ["align", "class", "contentEditable", "id", "innerHTML", "lang", "tabindex", "title", "value"];
    this.createGetSet(attributes);

    var methods = ["onclick", "ondblclick", "onmousedown", "onmouseup", "onmouseover", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onkeypress", "onkeydown", "onkeyup"];
    this.createGetSet(methods);
  }

  DivWrapper.prototype.createGetSet = function(attributes) {
    // for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
    var _this = this;
    attributes.forEach(function(attribute) {
      var getter = function() {
        return _this.div[attribute];
      };
      var setter = function(val) {
        _this.div[attribute] = val;
      };
      Object.defineProperty(_this, attribute, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter
      })
    })
  }

  DivWrapper.prototype.setAttribute = function(attribute, value) {
    this.div[attribute] = value;
  }
  DivWrapper.prototype.getAttribute = function(attribute) {
    value = null;
    try {
      value = this.div[attribute];
    } catch (e) {}
    return value;
  }

  return DivWrapper;
})();
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with that code?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Let's say I create an editable combo box - this class would wrap it and (hopefully) allow using it as I would any other HTML element. The code above works - it is just limited in the major way of not being able to implement interface Node.

Comment: Why souldn't you extend the HTMLElement? This is exactly how the custom elements api works. See here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements

Comment: @OlivierKrull - Thanks for the link. The article [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) has been cited as to why not to extend the DOM. Is the link you provided newer, a matter of opinion, or somehow different? In addition to creating new elements, I will be wrapping existing ones to extend their functionality. The link you provided would make that simpler I believe

Comment: Yes custom elements/components api is quiet new and is the way how to create custom web components today. You can nest them one in each other and build your whole application like this. I'm not sure if they're fully supported in every browser at the moment but there are some polyfills and shims. As far that I know all major browsers are working on support them natively in near future. In my opinion this is the future of front- end development. Not sure if this answers your question? Read more about it it's great ;-)

Comment: If you want to work work with custom elements you may want to take a look at googles Polymer framework, which adds some sugar on top of the api. https://www.polymer-project.org/